# How can I diagnose my log file to work out why my server load was 9.6?

Tags: apache-2.2

My Apache web server died so I ran the following command

killall -9 sys-snap.sh

And then restarted httpd.  My log file is here:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12337149/30.log

I can't make much sense of it I still don't understand why the server died

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not your Apache error log.

You should check /var/log/apache2/error.log and see if anything relevant is in there.

Comment: SIGTERM was my manual restart.  Before that nothing particularly interesting

[Sun Feb 20 06:10:14 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/html/whm-server-status
[Sun Feb 20 06:11:41 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/html/whm-server-status
[Sun Feb 20 06:12:50 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/html/whm-server-status
[Sun Feb 20 06:21:55 2011] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down